# PayPal payment API error python

Tags: python, paypal

I'm trying to execute payment via Paypal API and i'm facing errors.
I'm using this documentation - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

First I'm making this response - [enter link description here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create)
and i'm getting the response just fine.

Next im making redirect to approval_url from the the given response payment  creation.

Now, the client approve the payment using execute request [enter link description here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_execute).

now, i'm facing problem which i'm always receivng error that token is not recognize on the system,

```
'{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"The token passed in was not found in the system"}'
```

Comment: Did the token passed during payment execute was same just like the one on the payment creation?

Comment: @amuroray yes indeed

Comment: well, my mistake, been executing request to production instead of sandbox, oops :0